# Pandas: How to revert pct_change to the original value, with the initial value?

Tags: python, pandas

It is usual to use .pct_change() to have the daily change of time-series data.

Now I want to have the original value by using the pct_change result.

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [44, 45, 33, 56, 60]
})

df['pct_change'] = df['value'].pct_change() # get changes
initial_value=df['value'].values[0] # store the initial value
```

How can I use `df['pct_change']` and `initial_value` to get the `df['value']`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `cumprod`

```
df['pct_change'].add(1,fill_value=0).cumprod()*44
Out[200]: 
0    44.0
1    45.0
2    33.0
3    56.0
4    60.0
Name: pct_change, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The fill_value for the 1st row is really helped me!